# Getting list of SMS Messages?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

I can't find any reference/documentation how to get a list of SMS messages using WebWorks (for smartphone)? Is it possible?

I want to create my own app using WebWorks, im trying to find a way to get a list of SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply.

It's not possible to get list of sms even in native java application. You can only listen for incoming sms. But not sms that already received.